# Choosing only specific classes of CIFAR-10

Tags: keras

I'd like to use CIFAR-10 dataset but I want only the frog,dog,cat,horse and bird classes, I've used the following code so far :

```
  # Plot ad hoc CIFAR10 instances
  from keras.datasets import cifar10
  from matplotlib import pyplot
  from scipy.misc import toimage
  # load data
  (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
  # create a grid of 3x3 images
  for i in range(0, 9):
      pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
      pyplot.imshow(toimage(X_train[i]))
  # show the plot
  pyplot.show()
```

the cifar10.load_data() function loads the entire data, can I get only the desired classes?

Answer (score 4):

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
```

which contains all samples of 10 classes

choose index with respect to classes

```
index = np.where(y_train == 0)
X_train = X_train[indices]
y_train = y_train[indices]
```

which gives all 0th indices samples

Answer (score 0):

> the cifar10.load_data() function loads the entire data, can I get only the desired classes?

By using `load_data()` provided by `keras.datasets.cifar10` you can't do that. Also, checking other utilities on that [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/8ed57c168f171de7420e9a96f9e305b8236757df/keras/datasets/cifar10.py#L14) seems that only the `load_data()` method is provided.

However, you *can* do it if you **manually get and load the dataset**. For this you can try emulating the way [keras does it](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/8ed57c168f171de7420e9a96f9e305b8236757df/keras/datasets/cifar.py) (as well as the previous source code) on the CIFAR10 dataset.

Based on [this](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) help page (from where you can also download the dataset) seems that the classes frog, dog, cat, horse, and bird correspond to indexes 6, 5, 3, 7, and 2, respectively. This means you could use those indexes when extracting the data elements, so you can select the ones you need.

**Edit:** another option that could work better for you is to *discard the elements you don't wish from the `load_data()` call*. According to the Keras datasets [page](https://keras.io/datasets/), we see that method returns:

> - 2 tuples:
>
>   - x_train, x_test: uint8 array of RGB image data with shape (num_samples, 3, 32, 32).
>   - y_train, y_test: uint8 array of category labels (**integers in range 0-9**) with shape (num_samples,).

Knowing this you can **discard any element that does not have the 6,5,3,7,2 tags** which correspond to the classes you want.