# I need help to use only 8 out of 10 classes from cifar 10. Normally it loads all 10 classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision

I want to perform 8 class classification only and hence need to filter any 8 classes out of 10. Please help. Thank you!

Code to load cifar 10 is below

```
#Keras library for CIFAR-10 dataset
from keras.datasets import cifar10


#Downloading the CIFAR dataset
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test)=cifar10.load_data()

# I tried the following but its changing the array shape please help
#Train
for i in range(8):
  index = np.where(y_train == i)
  X_train = x_train[index]
  Y_train = y_train[index]

#Test
for i in range(8):
  index = np.where(y_test == i)
  X_test = x_test[index]
  Y_test = y_test[index]
```

Comment: How do you load it? Add some relevant code what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have used the load_data method to load cifar 10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing only specific classes of CIFAR-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213663/choosing-only-specific-classes-of-cifar-10)

Answer (score 1):

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
```

this contains all samples of 10 classes

you can choose index respect to classes

```
index = np.where(y_train.reshape(-1) == 0)
X_train = X_train[index]
y_train = y_train[index]
```

This gives all the samples with a label of 0

You can use this technique to load any specific classes you want.

Or if you want to load multiple classes, you can specify multiple conditions, like this:

```
class_0_index = np.where(y_train.reshape(-1) == 0)
X_train_class_0 = X_train[class_0_index]
y_train_class_0 = y_train[class_0_index]

class_1_index = np.where(y_train.reshape(-1) == 1)
X_train_class_1 = X_train[class_1_index]
y_train_class_1 = y_train[class_1_index]

class_2_index = np.where(y_train.reshape(-1) == 2)
X_train_class_2 = X_train[class_2_index]
y_train_class_2 = y_train[class_2_index]

X_train = np.concatenate((X_train_class_0, X_train_class_1, X_train_class_2))
y_train = np.concatenate((y_train_class_0, y_train_class_1, y_train_class_2)).reshape(-1,1)
```

This code loads all the samples with a label of `0`, `1` and `2`

Comment: #Train
for i in range(8):
  index = np.where(y_train == i)
  X_train = x_train[index]
  Y_train = y_train[index]

#Test
for i in range(8):
  index = np.where(y_test == i)
  X_test = x_test[index]
  Y_test = y_test[index]

Comment: But this returns me a narrowing array of the x_train, such as (50000, 32, 32, 3) becomes (500, 32, 3)

Comment: @MushfiratMohaimin But how can I make it work with multiple classes? I tried this with no luck: index = np.where((y_train.reshape(-1) == 0 or y_train.reshape(-1) == 1))

Comment: @MushfiratMohaimin It gives me this error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @MushfiratMohaimin The problem with this is it flattens the labels array, I have to use categorical crossentropy and adding the final layer like this: model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))  won't work. I am following your answer so you don't have to reply unless you want to provide specific information about this problem.

Comment: @MushfiratMohaimin Still the same problem, my output layers shouldn't get flattened, I need more than 1 neurons for the output layer, I am still looking forward for a tested working answer

Comment: @AbdullahAkçam This question is about selecting multiple classes from the cifar10 dataset. And your question is about the output layer of your model and the labels, that's a different question, so I suggest you start a question on that, if you're still facing that problem